# Add ASDoc documentation to Flex Builder help

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, hyperlink, asdoc

Is there any way to add my project documentation, generated with ASDoc, to the Flex Builder dynamic help?
Or not necessarily to the dynamic help, but somewhere so that Flex Builder searches it when I press F1.
I'm using Flex Builder 3 with SDK 3.2.0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash Builder 4 has built-in support for ASDoc comments in *Content Assist*.

Comment: I know, but I don't have Flash Builder 4.

Comment: I've switched to FlashDevelop, which at least displays an info tooltip.

Comment: any idea on how to generate docs for classes using a 3rd party library, but excluding the 3rd library doc gen ?